# How to use FULL Jquery.com files in Drupal content item?

Tags: javascript

I can use JS Injector and link to JS files through the info file, but what if the script is quite complicated with a lot of files and dependencies?

This accordion script has over 20 files...how to link all this and make it work?

Script is over here:

[Download Builder](http://jqueryui.com/download/#!version=1.11.4&components=1111111111000000000001111111111111111)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to enable the [jQuery Update](https://www.drupal.org/project/jquery_update) module, which provides support for all jQuery UI versions for Drupal 7 to jQuery 1.5.x, 1.7.x, 1.8.x, 1.9.x, 1.10.x, 2.1.x and jQuery UI 1.10.2.

Comment: Thank you, but that makes no difference, I already have Jquery update installed,  what do I do with the css files, images, external, ect...lots of files in there, not just Jquery version...

Comment: if you go to subfolder of jquery_update you will find all css and image files mendatory for jquery ui "jquery_update/replace/ui/themes/base"

Comment: You mean I go paste all the files I downloaded into there? What about images? Json files ect...?

Comment: which kind of functionality would you like to buid?